# Double Hop with ASP.Net website and NHibernate

Tags: sql-server, authentication, iis-7, kerberos

**Background:**

ASP.Net MVC website. Hosted on IIS7, intranet.

Database: SQL Server. Accessed via NHibernate.
In the connection string, access is set to `Integrated Security: SSPI`.
(Permissions to DB are Active-Directory-based.)

In short, this is a typical double-hop situation,
where I need to pass client's credentials to IIS, and from IIS to SQL Server.

**The Problem:**

The problem is a yellow screen of death, with the error:
`Login failed for user 'MyDomain\UserThatRunsAppPool'.`

**Things I tried doing to fix The Problem:**

- Configuring authentication to enable only *Windows Authentication*
  and *ASP.NET Impersonation*
- Setting Windows Authentication `Provider` to `Negotiate:Kerberos`
  (After disabling Kernel-mode authentication)
- Making sure that UserThatRunsAppPool's delegation is set to:
  '`Trust the user for delegation to any service (Kerberos only)`' in Active Directory
- Moving the NHibernate SessionFactory creation from `Application_BeginRequest()`
  to `Session_Start()`

**How successful I've been with my attempts to fix The Problem:**

Not at all.

---

**EDIT:**
I also tried setting IIS server's delegation to '`Trust the user for delegation to any service (Kerberos only)`' (in Active Directory).

Answer (score 3):

```
In short, this is a typical double-hop situation,
where I need to pass client's credentials to IIS, and from IIS to SQL Server.
```

You've hit upon the "delegation" problem.  If you want to remain sane, change your connection string to use a SQL username + password instead of SSPI.

If you feel like two weeks of frustrated debugging and quarreling with your domain admins, read [Fun with the Kerberos Delegation Web Site](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/11/25/fun-with-the-kerberos-delegation-web-site.aspx).

Comment: If he's getting login failed for `MyDomain\UserThatRunsAppPool` it means the call does not impersonate the HTTP caller. The fun with delegation would kick in only *after* that, once he successfully fixes the impersonation.